# update document.getElementById for same id name in different div

Tags: javascript, html

I know the problem here is because they both share the same id for input and for div. is there a way to specify the id of the specific div clicked like "this". without having multiple ids in my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $(this).on("click", ".descrip", function() {
        $(this).next('.def').slideToggle("slow");
      });



    });

    function addDef() {
      //window.alert (1);
      var def = document.getElementById("defInput").value;
      //window.alert (def);

      document.getElementById("addf").innerHTML += "<div class= 'descrip'> descrip </div>";
      document.getElementById("addf").innerHTML += "<div class= 'def'> " + def + " </div>";

    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="descrip"></div>
  <div class="def"></div>
  enter def for apple:
  <input type="text" id="defInput">
  <br>
  <br>

  <button onclick="addDef()">ADD</button>
  <div id="addf"></div>


  <div class="descrip"></div>
  <div class="def"></div>
  enter def for orange:
  <input type="text" id="defInput">
  <br>
  <br>

  <button onclick="addDef()">ADD</button>
  <div id="addf"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: _Identifiers in HTML must be unique_ Your HTML is invalid.

Comment: id's must be unique if you want scripts to work with them.  End of story.

Comment: Instead of ID, you should be using name='' or have a class. ID's in HTML should be unique.

Comment: **Identifiers in HTML must be unique. Your HTML is invalid** (just enforcing previous comments... :-)

Comment: If you changed the `id` to `name` you could use `.getElementsByName` to group them together. This won't solve your issue of your `addDef()` knowing which input to use though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element’s home subtree and must contain at least one character.
[W3C HTML 5.1 topic 3.2.5.1. The id attribute](https://w3c.github.io/html/dom.html#the-id-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

Directly from HTML5 Spec:

The id attribute specifies its element's unique identifier (ID). The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain any space characters.

An element's unique identifier can be used for a variety of purposes, most notably as a way to link to specific parts of a document using fragment identifiers, as a way to target an element when scripting, and as a way to style a specific element from CSS.

A possible solution is to change it to a class and then use the following nomenclature to target in your CSS or JS:

```
[class^="defInput-"], [class*=" defInput-"] {}
```

This will target any class that begins with defInput-

Answer (score 0):

Could you use class names rather than an id, then use `document.getElementsByClassName` instead?

```
  <button onclick="addDef('addf-1')">ADD</button>
  <div class="addf-1"></div>


  <div class="descrip"></div>
  <div class="def"></div>
  enter def for orange:
  <input type="text" id="defInput">
  <br>
  <br>

  <button onclick="addDef('addf-2')">ADD</button>
  <div class="addf-2"></div>
```

Then in your function:

```
 function addDef(className) {
      //window.alert (1);
      var def = document.getElementById("defInput").value;
      //window.alert (def);

      document.getElementsByClassName(className)[0].innerHTML += "<div class= 'descrip'> descrip </div>";
      document.getElementsByClassName(className)[0].innerHTML += "<div class= 'def'> " + def + " </div>";

    }
```

NOTE: I am not advocating this method, but this is a simple fix to your issue. I am making the assumption you were not aware of the existence of any other way to retrieve a node in the DOM besides `getElementById`.